# implement CRCCheck during SFTP file transfer

Tags: python, sftp, checksum, crc, pysftp

I have requirement like while sending data to sever using SFTP i need to use crccheck/cheksum for data integrity. I am newbie to python. For SFTP file transfer i am using pysftp module and using put() i am transferring one by one file to server.

```
    sftp.put(localpath=newlocalPath,remotepath=newremotePath,preserve_mtime=True)
```

So to check unsuccessful transfer, corrupted data transferred i need to implement CRCCheck. Is there any library for that in python? Any help please..

Comment: Thanks@Martin Prikryl . I used hashlib for generating md5 for local file and same i need to do for remote server. After that i need to match both local md5 and server md5. That i am facing IOError for remote fillepath due to sftp connection i think. haslib not able to connect remote path. Any suggestion please..

Comment: There's no suggestion. You cannot use hashlib with remote path. Read carefuly my answer to the duplicate question.